# Closed db connections are not released from pool

Tags: database, dropwizard

We are having dropwizard application using default configurations provided by dropwizard-jdbi for connecting to database.

Using the following to get sql connection object

```
Connection dbConnection = handle.getConnection();
```

Did a code walk-though and verified that the connections that are opened are closed.

But when i check `v$session`, I can see some inactive-sessions still present and are not getting released for long time.

I am using default connection pool provided by dropwizard.

Please let me know how to get the inactive sessions released.

Answer (score 0):

What are your settings in the configuration file for Dropwizard?

If you have a look at http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/manual/configuration.html#database and then the service configuration there is an option for connections to keep alive.

```
  # the minimum number of connections to keep open
  minSize: 10
```

But most of the times you want to have some connections open this will speed up your application. Your application doesn't have to validate and connect to the database again and again for every call. That's one of the purposes of a connection pool.

Comment: Thanks Ron ! Please find the configuration below -
  minSize: 200
  maxSize: 300
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  evictionInterval: 1s
  minIdleTime: 1 minute